# Происхождение слов «курьез» и «кьюрио́сити»

Tags: этимология, заимствования, индоевропеистика

Марсоход третьего поколения «Кьюрио́сити» (англ. Curiosity, МФА: [ˌkjʊərɪˈɒsɪti] — любопытство, любознательность).

Курьез – любопытный (интересный своей необычностью = редкий, странный, забавный, смешной) случай (обстоятельство, происшествие) или предмет.

Одного ли корня слова «курьез» и «кьюрио́сити»? Существуют ли в русском языке другие слова с этим корнем? В «обрусевшей» форме слова произносится «з» вместо «с». Это закономерность или случайность?

Answer (score 2):

Оба слова происходят от общего латинского корня (по Фасмеру: curiōsus" любознательный" или франц. curieuх); русское слово **курьёз(ный)** заимствовано через французский язык, второе слово - английское существительное (curiosity). Есть и прилагательное curious (любопытный, I'm curious = мне любопытно, интересно).

Answer (score 2):

1) **Современное значение слова**

КУРЬЁЗ, -а; м. [от франц. curieux (curieuse) – любопытный, забавный]

**Забавный, странный, смешной случай, происшествие.** ◊ Для (ради) курьёза; (устар.) из курьёза. Для забавы, для смеха.

2) **Происхождение**

Сначала в русском языке появилось прилагательное ***курьёзный***: в форме ***куриозный***,  в Петровское время, со значением "любопытный". Существительное ***курьёз*** – более позднее, в словарях с 1864 года. Это заимствование из французского языка.

3) **Значение**

А вот во французском языке оно восходит **к латыни**: ***curiosus*** – заботливый, тщательный, от ***curo*** – стараюсь, забочусь.

В английском и французском языке также есть прилагательные с этим значением: ***curious*** (англ.), ***kurios*** (нем.), также существительное ***curiosity*** (англ) – любопытство, любознательность, пытливость, курьез. Поэтому **у всех этих слов один исторический корень.**

Как мы видим, значение слова со временем и при переходе от языка к языку **менялось**: заботливый – тщательный – ревностный, старательный // любопытный, любознательный //странный // смешной, забавный.

4) **Родственные слова**

В современном русском языке есть слова ***курьёз, курьёзный, курьёзность.*** Из латинского языка нам, к примеру,  досталось слово ***куратор***. КУРАТОР, [от лат. curator – попечитель, опекун].

5) **О произношении З и С**

В прилагательном ***курьёзный*** перед Н произносится звонкий З, поэтому там изначально писалась буква З. Это же написание сохранилось в более позднем существительном ***курьёз***.

Comment: Тогда выходит, что к родственным относятся и "прокуратор" и "прокурор" с "прокуратурой"?

Comment: У всех  этих слов  общий исторический корень, поэтому это исторически родственные слова. В современном языке у родственных слов  корень  имеет строго одно и то же значение.